# Using MySQL's Membership Provider without autogenerateschema

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, acl

How can one use his already existing ACL schema with MySQL's Membership Provider connector?

I for one do not want to use the autogenerated table schema, but am happy to alter my own tables to adapt to ASP.NET's rules. For instance I want to use customn table names.

How can I point the connector to use them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your own [custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx).